# Using shift function from cats effect

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I am trying to use cats effect shift function to run the code asynchronous.

The function implementation:

```
  def asyncSendMsg(producer: KkProducer)(record: KkRecord) : IO[Either[String, RecordMetadata]] =
    for {
      res <- trySendMsg(producer)(record).shift(BlockingFileIO).shift(Main)
    } yield(res)

  def trySendMsg(producer: KkProducer)(record: KkRecord): IO[Either[String, RecordMetadata]] =
    IO {
      try {
        Right(producer.send(record).get())
      } catch {
        case e: Exception => Left(e.getMessage())
      }
    }
```

Trying to compile, I receive:

```
[error] /home/developer/Desktop/scala/PureProducer/src/main/scala/TheProducer.scala:51:43: value shift is not a member of cats.effect.IO[Either[String,org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata]]
[error]       res <- trySendMsg(producer)(record).shift(BlockingFileIO).shift(Main)
[error]                                           ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Nov 13, 2017 2:18:06 PM
```

Which library do I have to import to use shift function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IO.shift` is defined on the companion object of `IO` (the API has changed between versions of cats), and you can use it in a for comprehension prior to invoking your IO call:

```
val nonBlockingExecContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))

val res = for {
  _ <- IO { println(Thread.currentThread().getName) }
  _ <- IO.shift(nonBlockingExecContext)
  _ <- IO { println(Thread.currentThread().getName) }
} yield ()

res.unsafeRunSync()
```

Yields:

```
main
pool-1-thread-1
```

Comment: @zero_coding When `unsafeRunSync()` returns, you're back on `main`.

Comment: And assigning a calculated value from another thread to a the variable in the main thread?

Comment: @zero_coding That's what `unsafeRunSync` will do.